# Taking Input from an external file in Python

Tags: python, file, input, output, external

If you ever came across a situation where you have test your program against a very large pile of input, you have wondered that if there's any way to shortcut o it.

> **There are certain methods often come very handy when you have to test your program time and space complexity while processing a large input**
>
> You cant always input some large input manually , so there's the method by which you can provide input to your program using external **txt** file
>
> **Below is my answer to it :)**

Comment: what are you trying to ask ?

Comment: nothing just providing the answer to my question , see below

Answer (score 1):

> You just write simple program and then run it from command line in any platform like Windows/ Linux.

`python program.py < input.txt > output.txt`

> **<,>** are redirection operators which simply redirects the stdin and stdout to input.txt and output.txt. This is the easiest way.

Alternatively, you can do the following

`import sys sys.stdin=open('input.txt','r') sys.stdout=open('output.txt','w')`

Alternatively you can do the following

`input=open('input.txt','r') 
 ouput=open('ouput.txt','w') 
 n=input.read() 
 output.write(n)`

> I prefer method 1 as it is simple and no need of file handling and this helps a lot in Codejam, FaceBook HackerCup. Hope it helps